# MapStuct partial implementation - Java

Tags: java, interface, mapping, pojo, mapstruct

My code goes like this,

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoMapper {
    DtoMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(DtoMapper.class);

    ExampleModel dtoToDdModel(ExampleDto exampleDto);

    ExampleDto someOtherEntityToDto(OtherEntity otherEntity);
}
```

```
public class DtoMapperImpl implements DtoMapper {
    @Override
    public ExampleDto someOtherEntityToDto(OtherEntity otherEntity){
        if ( OtherEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        // Conversion
    }

    // I don't want to define dtoToDdModel
}
```

Is it possible to only provide implementation of `someOtherEntityToDto` in `DtoMapperImpl`? While `dtoToDdModel` follows the default mapping provided by MapStruct?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apply below annotation in DtoMapper interface

@InheritInverseConfiguration
ExampleModel dtoToDdModel(ExampleDto exampleDto)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct will only implement the abstract methods. Which means that if you provide a custom default methods then MapStruct will not implement it.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoMapper {
    DtoMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(DtoMapper.class);

    default ExampleModel dtoToDdModel(ExampleDto exampleDto) {
        //TODO write implementation
    }

    ExampleDto someOtherEntityToDto(OtherEntity otherEntity);
}
```

Note: the `@Mapper` does not have to be an `interface` it can also be an abstract class.

Comment: MapStruct 2.x will map default methods

Comment: What do you mean by that @evigis